# I have a project in react native when i try to run the app, only see the splash screen, then it close

Tags: react-native, expo

[Here a pick of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA53Z.png)

my dependencies
`"devDependencies": { "@babel/core": "^7.20.0", "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0", "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0", "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.0", "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2", "@types/jest": "^29.2.1", "@types/react": "^18.0.24", "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0", "babel-jest": "^29.2.1", "eslint": "^8.19.0", "jest": "^29.2.1", "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.7", "prettier": "^2.4.1", "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0", "typescript": "4.8.4" }`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have a project in react native when i try to run the app, only see the splash screen